# find search item plus 4 lines before and after

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I am using `notepad++` and would like to find the context in which a particular string occurs.

So the search string is `0wh.*0subj` and I would like to find this search item plus 4 lines immediately before and after it.

```
eg: xxx means whatever is on a new line. the search result should be:
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
0wh.*0subj
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

I have tried `using \n\r` but its not working. Any assistance afforded would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: This is not programming issue. At least before the last edit. Now it looks different ;)

Comment: If you're using Notepad++, then whenever you found "0wh.*0subj" or anything that you want to search, then you can also see the four lines preceding and after, right? Why do you need a specific regex for it? Do you intend to replace it?

Answer (score 6):

This will work in Notepad++ (tested):

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){4}0wh\.\*0subj[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){4}
```

On the screenshot, note that the 555 line is not selected. It is just the current line.

[image: SO N++]

**Explain Regex**

```
(?m)                     # set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                         # matching start and end of line) (case-
                         # sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                         # (matching whitespace and # normally)
(                        # group and capture to \1 (4 times):
  ^                      #   the beginning of a "line"
  [^\r\n]*               #   any character except: '\r' (carriage
                         #   return), '\n' (newline) (0 or more times
                         #   (matching the most amount possible))
  \R+                    #   'R' (1 or more times (matching the most
                         #   amount possible))
){4}                     # end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                         # quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                         # repetition of the captured pattern will be
                         # stored in \1)
0wh                      # '0wh'
\.                       # '.'
\*                       # '*'
0subj                    # '0subj'
[^\r\n]*                 # any character except: '\r' (carriage
                         # return), '\n' (newline) (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
\R+                      # 'R' (1 or more times (matching the most
                         # amount possible))
(                        # group and capture to \2 (4 times):
  ^                      #   the beginning of a "line"
  [^\r\n]*               #   any character except: '\r' (carriage
                         #   return), '\n' (newline) (0 or more times
                         #   (matching the most amount possible))
  \R+                    #   'R' (1 or more times (matching the most
                         #   amount possible))
){4}                     # end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                         # quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                         # repetition of the captured pattern will be
                         # stored in \2)
```