# Using Baregrep is there a regex solution to see surrounding lines around a matched line?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a line in text files along with +/- 2 lines (above and below) the matched line using Baregrep.

I have looked at several threads on Stackoverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526216/select-the-next-line-after-match-regex), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193251/regex-to-get-the-words-after-matching-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238348/find-search-item-plus-4-lines-before-and-after). However, none of the solutions in these posts have worked for me using Baregrep search.

Say I have the following three lines:

```
01:51:24:469,   0.000000,   0.000000,  0, -1,000000,0,   0,0,0,9,0, -1,  0, -1,000000,000000,000000,000000,000000,XYZ
01:53:27,           ,           ,   ,   ,      , ,    , , , , ,   ,   ,   ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,ABC
01:57:07:308,  43.715645, -79.810035,215, -1,001461,0,   0,0,0,1,2, -1,  4, -1,000000,000000,000000,000000,000000,EFG
```

My matched line is the middle one (ABC). In addition to ABC, I'd also like to see the top line before it (XYZ) and the bottom one (EFG).

Is there a regex solution which works with Baregrep (specifically) which I can use to look for surrounding context lines of a matched line?

Comment: you can with sed and holding pattern. It's not trivial though

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to use sed with Baregrep?